# Compute $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^{-1/2}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^{-2/3}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be absolutely continuous. Suppose that $f(0) = 0$ and $f' \in L^p([0,1])$ for some $p$. For each of the following values of $p$, prove that the given limit exists, and find its value:

1. $p = 2$; $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^{-1/2} f(x)$;
2. $p = 3$; $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^{-2/3} f(x)$.

Comment: Any help, or at least any guidance to a section of one of the standard real analysis textbooks, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 and 2 are similar, and we need apply Holder's inequality.

$f$ is absolutely continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=\int_{[0,x]}f^\prime(y)\;\mathrm{d}y$
$$ |x^{-\frac{1}{2}}f(x)|\le x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \int_{[0,x]}|1\cdot f^\prime(y)|\;\mathrm{d}y\le x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot(\int_{[0,x]}1^2\;\mathrm{d}y)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int_{[0,x]}|f^\prime(y)|^2\;\mathrm{d}y)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int_{[0,x]}|f^\prime(y)|^2\;\mathrm{d}y)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|f^\prime\chi_{[0,x]} \|_2
$$

Since $f^\prime \in L^2([0,1])$, the desired results follows by Dominated Convergence Theorem.